# Schedule for execution (I am planning to execute my entire .xml file at particular time)

Tags: java, schedule

By using Java only I am planning to make a schedule for execution of entire suite. For example, tomorrow morning by 6am i want to execute my file.

Comment: Start with [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you ask how to do this? Did you already **research**? Can you show us your attempts? Please read [ask], thanks. Usually such stuff is done using **cronjobs**. If you, however, want to stay in Java only, you will need to build some application that constantly runs in the background and checks time. If time has come it triggers the execution of your program.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want a Java-only solution, you will need to have a Java program running in the background, an the tasks could be scheduled using a `java.util.Timer` or a `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: Probably better suited as comment since it doesn't fully answer the question. However, in the current state the question actually is missing a lot of necessary information (as defined in [help]). So for a full and adequate answer waiting for edits would probably be the better option.